# how to do a simple login and registration in ember.js with couchdb

Tags: ember.js

I have integrated couchdb using pouchdb in emberjs. Its storing and retrieving data.
Now i have to create a login for that. Is there anything like devise gem like rails that create automated login session. If not what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to Devise in Ember-land is [Ember Simple Auth](https://ember-simple-auth.com/). You can make it talk to practically any backend - it even has an adapter to Devise in the core package, but you can roll your own easily if your server's semantics require to do so.